# Compile C from C++ Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio

I'm looking for a clean or simple way to programmitically compile c program from C++ application on windows.

My `creator.exe` executable written in C++ should take `NAME` constant from user and compile `result.c` with this constant finaly returning to user the compiled `result.exe` file.

Example:

```
// result.c
#ifndef NAME
    #define NAME"undefined"
#endif

int main() {
  printf("Welcome %s\n", NAME);
  return 0;
}
```

On linux it is easy as I can just invoke:

```
system("gcc result.c -DNAME Bob -o result");
```

I'm new to windows and maybe there is a cleaner way to perform such compilation then using system command.

**Update**

I'm very happy to see so many helpful answers:) I've read all of them and decided I will use `system` function. Now I don't want to set all the environment variables myself as it is strongly discouraged by Microsoft. I would like to use `Developer Command Prompt for VS2019` as it has all those variables already correctly set. From `Developer Command Prompt` I would like to execute `msbuild` to compile the `result.c` source code.

Now the problem is I'm not sure whether it is possible to invoke `msbuild` under `Developer Command Prompt` from C++?

What I mean by this is something like:

```
#define DEV_CMD "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat"

sprintf_s(cmd, "cmd \/S \/C \"\"%s\"\" && msbuild \/p:DefineConstants=\"DEBUG;NAME=\"%s\"\" ..\\result\\result.vcxproj", DEV_CMD, "Bob");

/* cmd /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"" && msbuild /p:DefineConstants="DEBUG;NAME="Bob"" ..\result\result.vcxproj */
system(cmd);
```

The above of course does not work as && will open `Developer Command Prompt` in one process and then it will run `msbuild` in other process.

Comment: You can do the same on Windows. Install MinGW, add the binaries to your `PATH` and call `system("gcc result.c -DNAME Bob -o result");`. IMHO a cleaner way is some kind of script like a Makefile or PowerShell script

Comment: There are [command line tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019) available for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use `cl.exe` instead of `gcc`.
In order to define something you will need to set `cl` environment variable.

So the following should help:

```
system("set CL=%CL% /DNAME#\"Bob\"");
system("cl result.c /out:result.exe");
```

Read MSDN for more options:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables?view=vs-2019